# Expressions similar to "to the core"

Tags: phrase-request

Consider these expressions:

> The whole firm is a sham to the core.
>
> Their football team is gutsy and resolute to the core.

What expressions similar to "to the core" can I use here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> He was resolute *to the bone*
>
> They were corrupt *through and through*
>
> She was *utterly* distressed
>
> They were dishonest *to the last man*
>
> *Every bone in his body* was honest / He *didn't have a* dishonest *bone in his body*
>
> She *lived and breathed* dedication

Answer (score 1):

Also consider *[body and soul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_and_Soul)*, *[full-out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/full-out)*, *[full-bore](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/full-bore)*, *[essentially](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/essentially)*, *[quintessentially](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quintessentially)*, and *[intrinsically](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intrinsically)*.